# Yii2 redirecting to previous page after login

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-user

how to redirect the users after login,
i tried to use all of these :

```
    Yii::$app->request->getReferrer(); // printing the refferrer url to screen 
    $this->redirect(\Yii::$app->request->referrer)


     return \Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(\Yii::$app->getUser()->getReturnUrl($defaultUrl));
```

none of these above is working

```
 public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
                $this->goHome();
        //    $this->goHome();
        }

        /** @var LoginForm $model */
        $model = \Yii::createObject(LoginForm::className());
        $event = $this->getFormEvent($model);

        $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
       $baseurl = \Yii::$app->request->getAbsoluteUrl();
        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_BEFORE_LOGIN, $event);

        if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->getRequest()->post()) && $model->login()) {
            $this->trigger(self::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, $event);
           // return $this->redirect(\Yii::$app->request->referrer);
          //  return \Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(\Yii::$app->getUser()->getReturnUrl($defaultUrl));
           // return \Yii::$app->request->getReferrer(); // printing the refferrer url to screen :(!!
           return $this->redirect($baseurl);
         // return $this->redirect(\Yii::$app->request->referrer);; //this one is returning everthing to main page, because of line 147
          //  return $this->goBack();
        }

        return $this->render('login', [
            'model'  => $model,
            'module' => $this->module,
        ]);
    }
```

In the web.php config i have this :

```
$config =[ 
..//
'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            'enableUnconfirmedLogin' => true,
            'confirmWithin' => 21600,
            'cost' => 12,
            'enableFlashMessages' => true,
            'admins' => ['a'],
        ],
    //..
```

all of these above is just sending the user after login to the home page
what should i do please , i have searched every where read the documentations


After 4 hours of trying i tried to "Echo" the URL after requesting referrer ;
the referrer is working fine the problem is after login the page loads more than one time and here is the problem why it's not sending back to that page but sending people to the current page (login page) then if he is a user he is automatically sending home.

Comment: you are trying to do this if the user session expires while he is logged-in ?

Comment: @WardNsour Also show your `Login` model

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I think the problem is when person is redirected from product page to login in order to checkout, like an example. That's my guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is common and it is related to the issue that at the time when you post login, your actual referrer is login page - `actionLogin()`, so you are redirected back again and off course you get passed throughout the
condition that you are not the `Guest`. In order to handle this, you have to assign a referrer to a modal field, so it can be posted with the login information. So at the time when login is validated, you have the required referrer url in your field. Check if you have this field identified in your form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'referer')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
```

**Controller**

```
$form = new LoginForm();
//get previos viewed page url and store in the new model
$form->referer = Yii::$app->request->referrer;
if ($form->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
   if($form->login()){
      return $this->goBack((($form->referer) ? $form->referer : null));
   }
}
```

**LoginForm() model**

```
public $referer;
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //...
            ['referer', 'string'],
        ];
    }
```

After that, when it will be post request, this field will contain a referrer, which you will pass in your controller.

Further, if you use the yii2-user module, now it is possible and necessary in the config in the controllerMap to remove all forced redirects for the event "after logging in" (I commented them out):

```
...
'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => \dektrium\user\Module::className(),
            'admins' => ['adminname'],
            'enableConfirmation' => false,
            'modelMap' => [
                'User' => 'app\models\User',
                'UserSearch' => 'app\models\UserSearch',
                'Profile' => 'app\models\Profile',
            ],
            'controllerMap' => [
                'profile' => 'app\controllers\user\ProfileController',
                'security' => [
                    'class' => \dektrium\user\controllers\SecurityController::className(),
                    'on ' . \dektrium\user\controllers\SecurityController::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN => function ($e) {
                        /*if (Yii::$app->user->can('student free')) {
                            Yii::$app->response->redirect(array('/course'))->send();
                        }
                        if (Yii::$app->user->can('admin')) {
                            Yii::$app->response->redirect('http://site.ru/user/')->send();
                        }*/

                        //Yii::$app->response->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer)->send();
                    //    Yii::$app->response->redirect(array('/user/'.Yii::$app->user->id))->send();
                        //Yii::$app->end();
                    }
                ],
            ],
        ],
...
```

Comment: Hello sir, i am now getting a fatal error because of the 
<br>
$form = new LoginForm();
would you please tell me what to do , should i create a new method in controller or add the code you wrote to the existing method 
i am new to programming i am sorry

Comment: @WardNsour have you defined you model at the begining of the controller? like `use common\models\LoginForm;`? And what is the error description?

Comment: yes it's defined, ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function dektrium\user\models\LoginForm::__construct(), 0 passed in /home/t//.beget.tech/vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/controllers/SecurityController.php on line 160 and at least 1 expected

Comment: which part of the model should i post where the rules ?

Comment: I added some solution for `dectrium` user login. You have to specify this in the question right at the beginning. Try this.

Comment: sir when i searched for an answer i saw this solution i will update the post with the config web.php  and there there is not 'controller map' as shown in your comment

Comment: i have tried to add 'controller map' to the web.php inside config and i did everything you wrote but i am still getting the same error

Comment: You can try to keep your original code and just pass a variable in to your form with `referrer`. Create a hidden input and insert referrer value in to that label. After you make a post request check that parameter to get a real referrer string.

Comment: Sir would you please tell me how to get the value from the form as a referer

Comment: i guess the problem is when a guest click on the anchor tag to login , the anchor tag doesn't redirect the browser this is why the referrer is not working !!
[link](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php)
_ 'HTTP_REFERER'
The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted._

Comment: You answered the question sir, now believe that the problem is when clicking on submit button the page reloads one more time, in another words
the user come from www.example.com to www.example.com/login, when the user hits the submit button the form is activated and the page is realoded again to www.example.com/login and this is why i am getting for using referrer www.example.com/login and not www.example.com, inside the form 'enableClientValidation' => false, so i really don't know how to solve this problem yet, how to get the referrer before the user hit's login as soon as he get to /login

Answer (score 0):

I did it, with the help of @serghei Leonenco,
but i had these problems :

1. The page reloaded after pressing the button submit so the referrer was the login page always and this is why it kept sending users to main page.
2. I had to get the referrer before the form begin.
3. I had to pass the value of the referrer to a hidden input.
4. I had to check if the referrer is from my website or the guest got on login page from a 3rd party site.
5. Passed the value after checking, used redirect and Url::to('link', true) because the value i got from referrer was a full URL and i couldn't just redirect to a full link this is why i used Url::to with the true condition which means creating a new URL.

**View**

Notice that i used the referrer value before the form.

```
<div class="panel-body arab">
                **<?php $referer = \Yii::$app->request->referrer;?>**
                <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id' => 'login-form',
                    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                    'enableClientValidation' => false,
                    'validateOnBlur' => false,
                    'validateOnType' => false,
                    'validateOnChange' => false,
                ]) ?>
                **<?= $form->field($model, 'referer')->hiddenInput(['value' => $referer])->label(false) ?>**
                <?php if ($module->debug): ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'login', [
                        'inputOptions' => [
                            'autofocus' => 'autofocus',
                            'class' => 'form-control',
                            'tabindex' => '1']])->dropDownList(LoginForm::loginList());
                    ?>

                <?php else: ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'login',
                        ['inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control', 'tabindex' => '1']]
                    );
                    ?>

                <?php endif ?>

                <?php if ($module->debug): ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning">
                        <?= Yii::t('user', 'Password is not necessary because the module is in DEBUG mode.'); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?= $form->field(
                        $model,
                        'password',
                        ['inputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'tabindex' => '2']])
                        ->passwordInput()
                        ->label(
                            Yii::t('user', 'Password')
                            . ($module->enablePasswordRecovery ?
                                ' (' . Html::a(
                                    Yii::t('user', 'Forgot password?'),
                                    ['/user/recovery/request'],
                                    ['tabindex' => '5']
                                )
                                . ')' : '')
                        ) ?>
                <?php endif ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox(['tabindex' => '3']) ?>

                <?= Html::submitButton(
                    Yii::t('user', 'Sign in'),
                    ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block', 'tabindex' => '4']
                ) ?>

                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**Model**

Notice I used regex to make sure that the user got to login page using my website.

```
public function getReferer()
    {
        $getLink = \Yii::$app->request->post('login-form')['referer'];
        if(preg_match('/tajrobtak/', $getLink)){
        return $getLink;
        } else {
        return "";
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            $this->goHome();
        }

        /** @var LoginForm $model */
        $model = \Yii::createObject(LoginForm::className());
        $referery = $model->getReferer();
        $event = $this->getFormEvent($model);

        $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_BEFORE_LOGIN, $event);

        if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->getRequest()->post()) && $model->login()) {
            $this->trigger(self::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, $event);
            $this->redirect(Url::to($referery,true));
        }

        return $this->render('login', [
            'model'  => $model,
            'module' => $this->module,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: $referery = $model->getReferer(); is giving always empty with the exact process what you have suggested. Any suggestions? Can you please post your loginForm model as well?

Comment: Got it no worries, I was having different form ID :-) than your's, issue with copy paste :-D